# Is Application class data will persistent after wake up of application from long sleeping in Android?

Tags: android

i am using application class to save global data for all intents.So what happen if the application went to background and after 5 hours i launch the application from icon the data will available or not?

Answer (score 0):

The system can kill your app at any moment so you have to save things in some persistent storage.

Answer (score 0):

It's completely unpredictable. As per the documentation looks like android would try to keep proccess (and, so Your Application class) as long as resources allow. e.g. if some service with higher priority would need resources, Your process might be killed. However, there's no way You can predict it for sure.
I would suggest to utilize [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) or ContentProvider mechanism (depends on Your data) then Your last activity get stopped in order to be sure not to lose any essential data.

Comment: dear Sandrstar,i am using sharedPreferences to save all data. when application start i am fetching the data from SharedPreferences and assigning to Application class data.what my doubt is if application went for sleep mode(background) and one of my activity is stay live after wake up.is the data will be available in Application class or not.

Comment: yes, it'll retain, because Application is stick to process (and VM instance) for Your app and, so won't be killed before activities.